# CFT and the conformal group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

Equations 2-7 on page 21 of these notes, http://www.math.ias.edu/QFT/fall/NewGaw.ps seems to give a fairly compact definition of what a CFT is.

But I have two questions,

- This definition is specific to 2 dimensions. Is there an analogue of this definition for higher dimensions?
- I want to know if there is an equivalent definition of a CFT in terms of the conformal group in the specific dimension.

Like I would like to know if I can make precise a statement like this (for any dimension), "CFT is a QFT such that its Hilbert space splits into Verma modules and the correlation function of its primary fields is invariant under the conformal group in that dimension."

We do have odd-dimensional CFTs and there I don't know what is a "conformal group"!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conformal group is defined for any spacetime you want. The conformal group of d-dimensional Euclidean space, which has isometry group SO(d), is SO(d+1,1). The conformal group of d+1 dimensional Minkowski space, whose isometry group is SO(d,1), is SO(d+1,2). The defining property of the conformal group is that its the set of transformations that leave the metrix $g_{\mu\nu}$ invariant up to a scaling factor $e^{\omega(x)}$.

A more general definition for CFTs in d>2 dimensions is that a CFT is a QFT whose Hilbert space breaks up into representations of the conformal group and whose correlation functions are invariant under any conformal transformation (I don't believe we have to restrict to primary operators).

The special case of two dimensions is that the conformal algebra is infinite dimensional. The group of globally defined conformal transformations is still finite, but there are an infinite number of local conformal transformations. So 2d CFTs are a lot more restricted then higher dimensional CFTs.

For a good introduction look at 
https://sites.google.com/site/slavarychkov/

Comment: Here are my 2 questions rephrased better, (1) Isn't it true that the conformal group in $(d>1)+1$ Minkowski manifold is only locally isomorphic to $SO(d+1,2)$ and not globally? (2) Is there a proof for $(d>1)+1$ Minskowskian space-time that demand of the classical Lagrangian being invariant under Weyl rescalings of the metric implies that the Hilbert space of the corresponding QFT will split into $SO(d+1,2)$ representations? [...AFAI have seen this crucial link between the classical and the quantum picture is provable only on Riemann surfaces with a fixed metric...]

Comment: Also is it true that in a CFT Hilbert space all operators will be eigenoperators under commutation with the dilatation operator? (...because when one argues what is the highest-weight sate in a conformal module one looks for that operator among only such operators which commutes with the $K$ - and that is the primary...)

Comment: To answer your first question, yes the isomorphism is only local (typically). The conformal group of 3+1 dimensional Minkowski space is doubly covered by SO(4,2), which in turn is doubly covered by SU(2,2). 2) I think Weyl rescalings are in general a different beast then conformal transformations (rescaling of metric vs coordinate transformations) and there is no guarantee a conformally invariant lagrangian gives rise to a CFT. In general a clasically conformally invariant lagrangian gives rise to a CFT only if its a fixed point of the RG flow (or typically that the beta function vanishes)

Comment: And yes the Hilbert space of a CFT all operators will be eigenoperators of the dilatation operator. Basically thats how the Hilbert space is constructed, you start with the primary operators annihilated by K and construct all the other states in the conformal module via P.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! (1) So if SO(d+1,2) is only a local model for whatever one wants to call as the "conformal group" (the group of all conformal diffeomorphisms - diffeomorphisms which keep the metric invariant upto a Weyl rescaling)  then why should the Hlbert space of the CFT split under its representations? QFTs are supposed to see the full space-time and not just a local symmetry group - right? SO we are saying that no matter how complicated is the space-time topology a CFT on it will have its Hilbert space split under $SO(2,d+1)$!

Comment: (2) See the issue with Weyl resacalings is quite serious to my mind - because classically when thinking of a CFT in $(d>1)+1$ thats what we always do - we write down a Weyl invariant Lagrangian - and then as a QFT we think its Hilbert space to split under $SO(2,d+1)$ - one needs to know that this indeed follows!

Comment: (3) Do you have a reference where this is proven that all states in a CFT Hilbert space will be eigenoperators under the dilation generator? I have never seen such a proof! (...all arguments begin by assuming that such an eigenspace of dilation exists for a CFT and then one looks for the lowest among them and thats the one which commutes with $K$ and gets called the primary..)

Comment: 1) You're confusing local symmetry groups with local isomorphisms. A local symmetry is a symmetry whose parameter changes as a function of spacetime (think local U(1) gauge symmetry). I'm saying that as group manifolds, SO(d+1,1) is locally isomorphic to the conformal group of d-dimensional euclidean space. Its no more mysterious then that the circle (which is the same as U(1)) is isomorphic locally to the real line (which also forms a group under addition). Globally they differ but if we're concerned about small global transformations we can ignore the differences.

Comment: 2&3) I think a general statement is that the Hilbert space of a theory with a symmetry, that is some group of transformations that leave the generating functional of correlation functions invariant, decomposes as representations of that symmetry. I would look in Howard Georgi's text on Lie Algebras and Group theory for a discussion about this, but I dont know of any other references (I'll look though). Again, a classically conformally invariant lagrangian does not always give rise to a CFT, but if it does the preceding statement should hold.

Comment: As for more complicated space-time topologies, I don't have anything intelligent to say then that the conformal group will no longer be SO(d+1,2), which only holds for d+1 Minkowski space. That being said d-dimensional Euclidean space is conformally equivalent to the d-dimensional sphere so for most cases this is not really an issue.

Comment: I think you are missing my point - You are right that *"the Hilbert space of a theory with a symmetry, that is some group of transformations that leave the generating functional of correlation functions invariant, decomposes as representations of that symmetry"* - BUT - if an action is invariant under conformal diffeomorphisms then $SO(2,d+1)$ is NOT the full symmetry group of transformations (its only so locally!) - then why does the Hilbert space still split under its representations? (...and this happens irrespective of the topology of the locally $d+1$-Minkowskian space-time - right?...)

Comment: Ok you're question is really concerning CFTs on nontrivial spacetimes. Now as you said, the conformal diffeomorphisms do not give the full symmetry group, but they are a symmetry of the theory and should have be represented on the Hilbert space. Now if your CFT lives on a nontrivial geometry, you have added constraints from large diffeomorphisms, like modular invariance if your theory lives on the torus. However such situations are usually not considered in d>2 CFTs because although you can have your CFT live on a d-dimensional torus and require that it be invariant under SL(d,Z) large diffeos

Comment: but there is no simple connection to the dimensions of operators because we normally quantize radially. 2d is special here because T2=S1xS1. You could consider your theory to live on d-dimensional Euclidean space times the circle and this gives added constraints (generalized modular invariance) from finite temperature field theory. You could also consider your theory to live on the d-sphere but its conformally equivalent to flat space. For the most part, you'll see that the literature on d>2 CFTs is restricted to flat space, space with boundaries, and spheres.

Comment: I would recommend you look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4163v2.pdf, its the only paper that touches generalized modular invariance.